# How does DB2 alter table statement for adding multiple columns work?

Tags: sql, db2, alter-table

How does DB2 alter table statement for adding multiple columns work? Does it add columns sequentially and drop already added columns if a problem is encountered while adding a column? Is the order of the columns preserved? Is it better to call the alter table statement multiple times, once for each column, performance wise ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add columns multiple in one time like this :

```
alter table jgrun.tmp          
add column col1 varchar(15)    
add column col2 int default 0  
add column col3 varchar(10)
```

You can remove multiple column like this :

```
alter table jgrun.tmp    
drop  column col1        
drop column col2
```

If you must add/drop multiple columns you should use this method for perfomance (better on one by one)

Answer (score 1):

With Db2, the DDL (including alter table) is under transaction control, so if you want to make multiple alterations (create, drop, alter etc.) you can do it in a single unit of work subject to available transaction logging capacity. So multiple DDL statements can be a single atomic action, meaning that if one of them fails the whole transaction gets rolled back.

Depending on the platform that hosts Db2 (Z/OS, i-series, Unix/windows) and Db2 version, there are limits on the number of separate alterations to a table that can happen before Db2 will need  a reorg.  This can influence the number of ALTER statements you use (e.g. add more than one column in a single statement).

Performance may not be the determining factor for how you group alterations. Recoverability, space considerations, object dependencies, back-out, HA/DR considerations, change-window timings, availability matters, scheduling , code-dependencies, can determine the sequence you use. One size does not fit all.